# Process_run error while running a shell script in dart in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, shell, scripting

I am getting this error while i am running a shell script in a dart file. The shell script isn't working at all like not even an echo command is running. Are there any dependencies that need to be added or any other prerequisites.

[this is that dart code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y55Er.png)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:process_run/shell.dart';

class OTPService {
  static String generateOTP() {
    // Generate a 6-digit OTP
    Random random = Random();
    return (100000 + random.nextInt(900000)).toString();
  }

  Future<void> sendOTP(String email, String otp) async {
    try {
      //Run the shell script to send email with OTP
      final process = await Process.run(
          'send_email.sh', [email, otp]);

      // Check if the command was successful
      if (process.exitCode == 0) {
        print("Script output: ${process.stdout}");
      } else {
        print("Script error: ${process.stderr}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error running shell script: $e");
    }
  }
}
```

I/flutter (15820): Error running shell script: ProcessException: No such file or directory

What I was trying is a want to run a shell script in a android application. So,I used Process.run() in a dart file.

when this function got invoked it is showing this error.

NOTE: when run that shell script in normal terminal it is running.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.